# Raster color is changed when clipped with a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, color, pixel

I am using QGIS 3.16.9 and whenever I clip my satellite image bands according to the vector layer I made, it loses its original RGB color. Is there a way to maintain the color/values of the pixels?

Answer (score 7):

I guess, it is an expected behaviour. QGIS changes the color scheme depending on min/max values of new raster.

To keep the same scheme for the new raster:

- Right click on the former satellite image > Styles > Copy Style
- Right click on the clipped image > Styles > Paste Style

Comment: Alternatively, disable color stretching from Properties-Symbology-Band Rendering-Contrast enhancement.

Answer (score 6):

If this is something you do alot, you can also build a model to clip then apply a saved style:

1. Export the style as a QGIS Layer style file
2. Create a model which clip and then set the style using the style file:

[image]